# Appended input form unable to be submitted via POST

Tags: php, post, input, append, codeigniter-3

I have a form like this in my HTML side :

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" class="optradio" name="optMsg" value="user is no longer exist">user is no longer exist.</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radioOthersHolder">
        <label><input type="radio" class="radioOthers optradio" name="optMsg" value="0">others</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger margin-top">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

This is how I append my input control based on the radio select:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.optradio').change(function(){
        if($('.radioOthers').is(':checked')) { 
            $('.radioOthersHolder').append('<input type="text" name="txtOthers" class="form-control txtOthers" max="160" placeholder="State your message here." required />');
        } else {
            $('.txtOthers').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Then on my PHP side, I tried to grab all the POST data and check the value but it seems like my appended input is not recognized if I select the others radio and submit. I'm not sure what might it caused.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    if(isset($_POST['optMsg']) && !empty($_POST['optMsg'])){
        if($_POST['optMsg'] == 0){
            if(isset($_POST['txtOthers']) && !empty($_POST['txtOthers'])){
                $reasonMsg = $_POST['txtOthers'];
            }
        } else {
            $reasonMsg = $_POST['optMsg'];
        }

        print_r($_POST); exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is just fine. but you have to set `value="1"` in this line

```
<input type="radio" class="radioOthers optradio" name="optMsg" value="0">others</label>
```

when you set the `value="0"` the following condition returns false and you don't get the result.

```
if(isset($_POST['optMsg']) && !empty($_POST['optMsg'])
```

**Note** `isset()` check if variable is set or not.
`empty()` check if value is not empty or **0**.
So `value="0"` cause the problem.

Comment: Yes you got it right. I've just figured it out so I changed my value to a string which is *others*. Now it's working fine